# Permission denied for IAM policy to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to set up a resize image lambda using [Resize Images on the Fly with Amazon S3, AWS Lambda, and Amazon API Gateway | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/).

However, the IAM policy is not working. It does not have access to the S3 bucket.

I tested it in the IAM Policy Simulator (testing for S3 PutObject) and it says `Implicitly denied (not matching statements)`.

I edited the policy according to [Grant a Lambda Execution Role Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/) but it gives me the same error.

Here is my bucket policy (edited to change this to the role below instead of root, still denied through IAM Policy Stimulator):

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-account-number>::role/<my-role-name>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my IAM role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are my S3 Redirection rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>MYAPIENDPOINT.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>default/resize?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Lambda function is running as the root user? (I don't even know if this is possible, but you probably don't want to be doing that)

You can find out the role for your Lambda function using this command:

```
aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME | grep Role
```

The value you see is what you should use in your bucket policy:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-account-number>:role/service-role/foo-bar-baz"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I had a policy before the root but it also doesn't work in the IAM policy stimulator... I tried to stimulate the policy to verified it can "PutObject" on S3, but I get the error denied.

Edited to show role in s3 json - the main issue is that the role itself does not have access to the s3 bucket when tested in the policy stimulator, and I presume that's why the whole setup doesn't work?

Comment: Your edited bucket policy has two `:` characters in the role ARN where there should only be one. Does your bucket policy also have this typo?

Comment: If I remove the double `:` after `iam` aws says it is invalid. Your example also has two `:` characters? Or did you mean somewhere else?